# Has anyone quantified how many transcription factor-inducer pairs are available for use in genetic circuits?

Tags: synthetic-biology, transcription-factor

I know of at least 12 orthogonal small molecule sensors which come from the "marionette" strain paper (https://www.nature.com/articles/s41589-018-0168-3#Sec9). There are others scattered throughout the literature. Has anyone tried to count the number of these that exist. Let's, for now, exclude the fact that some may only work in specific organisms. I am curious about the total count of these systems and how quickly (slowly?) we are expanding the synbio toolkit.